# How to specify field choices in django inlineformset

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I wish to only display a subset of the choices for a model form field. E.g Depending on the url the user is at I might want only 'weight gain' and 'parkinsonism' displayed as options for the 'se_name' field.

I can work out how to get the url as a parameters in the view (`p = self.request.GET.get("p", None)`) But I cant work out how to use this parameter to limit the choices available.

This is the formset

```
SideeffectFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    Case,
    SideEffect,
    fields=("se_name",),
    widgets={'concern': RangeInput()},
    extra=0,
    min_num=1,
    validate_min=True,
)
```

Which is based on the model:

```
class SideEffect(TimeStampedModel):

    SE_CHOICES = [
        ("weight_gain", "Weight Gain"),
        ("parkinsonism", "Parkinsonism"),
        ("dystonia", "Dystonia"),
        ("none", "None"),
    ]

    se_name = models.CharField("",max_length=200, choices=SE_CHOICES, default="none")

    case = models.ForeignKey(Case, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And the form is rendered by this view:

```
class CaseView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    model = Case
    template_name = "se_balance/se_balance.html"
    
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        p = self.request.GET.get("p", None)
        sideeffect_formset = SideeffectFormSet(queryset=SideEffect.objects.none(),)

        return self.render_to_response(
            { "sideeffect_formset": sideeffect_formset,
              "sideeffect_formsethelper": SideEffectFormSetSetHelper,
            }
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the choices of a field in a formset dynamically you need to define a custom form class that does the choice alteration on `__init__`

```
from django import forms
from .models import SideEffect

class SideEffectForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = SideEffect
        fields = ['se_name']

    def __init__(self, *args, p, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if p == 'foo':
            self.fields['se_name'].choices = [
                ("weight_gain", "Weight Gain"),
                ("parkinsonism", "Parkinsonism"),
            ]
        else:
            ...
```

Use the form class in your formset

```
SideeffectFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    Case,
    SideEffect,
    form=SideEffectForm,
    extra=0,
    min_num=1,
    validate_min=True,
)
```

Then in your view you can [pass custom parameters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/formsets/#passing-custom-parameters-to-formset-forms) to the formset form

```
sideeffect_formset = SideeffectFormSet(queryset=SideEffect.objects.none(), form_kwargs={'p': p})
```